# C++11: increment time_point by one second

Tags: c++11, clock, c++-chrono

If I have a

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

variable, how can I define another time_point variable `t2` such that it represents the time point exactly **one second** after of `t1`?

Something like `auto t2 = t1 + "1s"`. What should I replace "1s" with?

Comment: Use a suitable [duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).

Comment: std::chrono::seconds(1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using C++14 (VS-2015, or `-std=c++14` with gcc or clang), then:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto t2 = t1 + 1s;
```

If you are using C++11:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto t2 = t1 + seconds{1};
```

If you don't want to make a copy, but add 1 second to `t1` itself, `+=` is also ok:

```
t1 += 1s;
t1 += seconds{1};
```